# How to extract xml response in karate framework if response itself has <response> tag in it

Tags: karate

response

result

result

response

I have something like above all are xml tags
Now when I do * print response.response it doesn't take it
as response is the actual response of api
Please suggest

Comment: I'm quite sure this needs a proper example including your code.

Comment: I would be great if you use [proper code formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and post a complete example.